# Prevent loop from stopping without having result from the query function firebase

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

So I query a set of nodes in firebase in order to get a value depends if the id inputted is exists, problem here is after the function returns the for loop stops looping though the return will exits a loop. So what would be the best way on querying data synchronously without stopping the loop after a return called. Hope someone helps snippet of the code attached below

```
     loginIdentification = ['bfp','ndrmmc','pnp','rta'];
for (var counter = 0; counter < this.loginIdentification.length; counter++) { // loop the possible place of the data
              console.log('loop',counter);
              return this.loginFiredatabase.ref('users/' + this.loginIdentification[counter] + '/' + authData.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => { // authdata.uid is the id of the user
                console.log('await');
                  if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot));
                    return snapshot;
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log('not exists');
                  }
                });
              }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. But if you don't want to exit the loop, don't use `return` in there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if i will do that the loop will continue without trying to query in the firebase, the code must execute like this loop->query->if exists break;else->loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to find the first user identification in the array that already exists in the database. If that's the case, it'd be something like this:

```
function findMatch(ids, callback) {
  var id = ids.shift;
  this.loginFiredatabase.ref('users/' + this.loginIdentification[counter] + '/' + authData.uid)
      .once('value', function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          callback(snapshot);
        else if (ids.length > 0) {
          findMatch(ids, callback);
        }
        else {
          callback();
        }
      });
}
```

The trick about this function is that it checks one ID from the array at a time. Since data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, it waits until it gets a result before trying the next item.

You'd call it like:

```
findMatch(['bfp','ndrmmc','pnp','rta'], function(result) {
  if (result) {
    console.log("Found match: "+result.val());
  }
  else {
    console.log("No match found");
  }
}
```